# How do I replace the screen of a Dell Inspiron 1545?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

I got a new screen for a Dell Inspiron 1545. The old screen says

> Dell Inspiron 1545 LP156WH1 (TL)(C1​) HD

and the new one says

> Dell Inspiron 1545 LP156WH1 (TL)(C1​) LCD

Does that make a difference? All I can get to work on the new screen is the backlight. The old screen had a crack. Now when I plug the old one in, it will not turn on at all. Could I have blown the inverter or messed up the cable?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously physical damage could be an issue you will just have to open it up and inspect to see if there is any.

If you bought a new screen from Dell they will be able to assist you with any issue you have regarding install and if it is the correct model.

If the screen just got dropped or something there is likely no damage to the system; as long as the dropping didn't cause it.

You may need to update your bios and video card drivers for the new screen; there is a possability your bios is only setup for HD and your new screen is standard def or so it sounds.

I would check into the above few things I mentioned hopefully that will resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect that you have a loose connection somewhere.  Obviously power is getting to the display, but the data cable may not be fully inserted, or may be upside down.  I haven't tooled on your particular model, but I do know that the data cable can be a bit finicky.

The HD vs LCD on the display shouldn't be too much of a concern, as the rest of the model name is the same.  There may be differences between the two displays, but connections and data interfaces should be the same.